# PERL: String Replacement on file

Tags: perl, replace

I am working on a script to do a string replacement in a file and I will read the variables and values and files from a configuration file and do string replacement.

Here is my logic to do a string replacement.

```
sub expansion($$$){
my $f = shift(@_) ; # file Name
my $vname = shift(@_) ; # variable name for pattern match
my $value = shift(@_) ; # value to replace
my $n = "$f".".new";

    open ( O, "<$f") or   print( "Can't open $f file: $!");
    open ( N ,">$n" ) or print( "Can't open $n file: $!");
    while (<O>)
    {
        $_ =~ s/$vname/$value/g;  #check for pattern
        print N "$_" ;
    }
    close (O);
    close (N);


}
```

In my logic am reading line by line in from input  file ($f) for the pattern and writing to a new file  ($n) .

Instead of write to a new file is there any way to do a string replacement the original file when I try to do the same it has only empty file with no contents.

Comment: perl has an `exp` builtin; choose another name for your sub.  also, don't use prototypes; they aren't designed to do what prototypes in other languages do and you are better off without them.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from copying the new file to the old file name?

Comment: I updated the function name even though in my original script i was using different name..thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @TLP : actually once the replacement is done am copying the new to old one however I want to do a diff to the user (for preview option) it is works fine only for one string replacement in one file in case if i have multiple files and multiple variables to replace am wondering it is not going to workout.. so is there any way to do other method of replacement..

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about there. Why would it be easier to do a diff if you only change the original? You need two files to do a diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub inplace_expansion($$$){
    my $f = shift(@_) ; # file Name
        my $vname = shift(@_) ; # variable name for pattern match
        my $value = shift(@_) ; # value to replace

    local @ARGV = ( $f );
    local $^I = '';
    while (<>)
    {
        s/\Q$vname/$value/g;  #check for pattern
        print;
    }
}
```

or, my preference would run closer to this (basically equivalent, changes mostly in formatting, variable names, etc.):

```
use English;
sub inplace_expansion {
  my ( $filename, $pattern, $replacement ) = @_;
  local @ARGV = ( $filename ),
        $INPLACE_EDIT = '';
  while ( <> ) {
    s/\Q$pattern/$replacement/g;
    print;
  }
}
```

The trick with `local` basically simulates a command-line script (as one would run with `perl -e`); for more details, see [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).  For more on `$^I` (aka `$INPLACE_EDIT`), see [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

(For the business with `\Q` (in the `s//` expression), see [`perldoc -f quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).  This is unrelated to your question, but good to know.  Also be aware that passing regex patterns around in variables—as opposed to, e.g., using literal regexes exclusively— can be vulnerable to injection attacks; Perl's built-in [taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode) is useful here.)

EDIT: David W. is [right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668447/559827) about prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

Do not. Never, ever<sup>1</sup>. Don't you dare, Don't even think of, do not use subroutine prototyping. It is horribly broken (that is, it doesn't do what you think it does) and is [dangerous](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966).

---

Now, we got that out of the way:

Yes, you can do what you want. You can [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a file as both read and writable by using the mode `<+`. So far, so good.

However, due to buffering, you cannot use the standard read and write methods to read and write to the file. Instead, you need to use [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) and [syswrite](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html).

Then, what you need to do is read the *line*, use [sysseek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysseek.html) to go back to the start of where you read, and then write to that spot.

Not only is it very complex to do, but it is full of peril. Let's take a simple example. I have a document, and I want to replace my curly quotes with straight quotes.

```
$line =~ s/“|”/"/g;
```

That should work. I'm replacing one character with another. What could go wrong?

If this is a UTF-8 file (what Macs and Linux systems use by default), those curly quotes are two-byte characters and that straight quote is a single byte character. I would be writing back a *line* that was shorter than the *line* I read in. My buffer is going to be off.

Back in the days when computer memory and storage were measured in kilobytes, and you serial devices like reel-to-reel tapes, this type of operation was quite common. However, in this age where storage is vast, it's simply not worth the complexity and error prone process that this entails. Stick with reading from one file, and writing to another. Then use `unlink` and `rename` to delete the original and to rename the copy to the original's name.

A few more pointers:

- Don't `print` if the file can't be opened. Use `die`. Otherwise, your program will simply continue on blithely unaware that it is not working. Even better, use the pragma [use autodie;](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html), and you won't have to worry about testing whether or not a read/write failed.
- Use scalars for file handles.

That is instead of

```
open OUT, ">my_file.txt";
```

use

```
open my $out_fh, ">my_file.txt";
```

- And, it is highly recommended to use the three parameter open:

Use

```
open my $out_fh, ">", "my_file.txt";
```

- If you aren't, always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

In fact, your Perl syntax is a bit ancient. You need to get a book on [Modern Perl](http://modernperl.net). Perl originally was written as a hack language to replace shell and awk programming. However, Perl has morphed into a full fledge language that can handle complex data types, object orientation, and large projects. Learning the modern syntax of Perl will help you find errors, and become a better developer.

---

<sup>1.</sup> Like all rules, this can be broken, but only if you have a clear and careful understanding what is going on. It's like those shows that say *"Don't do this at home. We're professionals."*